# Save zoomed image in a picturebox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox

I'm a newbie in vb.net (windows app) programming. How can I save a zoomed image in a picturebox.

See, I have a panel and put a picturebox (set to zoom) inside and set the panel to autoscroll to accomodate the size of the image. I can zoom in and out of the image. I can save the picture as is using a memorystream and save it to the database (access). But the thing I don't know is how to save the current size of the image to the size and current position of the image relative to the size of the panel.

This is what my project looks like. See I can load an image and save the picture as is to the database.

[What my project looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNHgL.jpg)

My question is, how to save the current location and size relative to the panel size of the image if I zoom it?

[How to save this image and resize the picturebox to the size of the panel and the current location of the zoomed image and the image itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2TQv.jpg)

I hope you understand my question (sorry if my english is bad, it is not my native language).

------edit------

UPDATE: I was able to save the zoomed image from the picturebox inside the panel. I used @dr.null and @jtxkopt suggestion and it works somehow. BUT the problem is, the output has also drawn the scrollbars on the panel.

Output:
[This is my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvLrh.png)

This is my code:

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg; *.png; *.bmp"
    Panel3.HorizontalScroll.Visible = False
    Panel3.VerticalScroll.Visible = False
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim imageRectangle = New Rectangle(Point.Empty, picUser.Image.Size)
        Dim safeCropRectangle = Rectangle.Intersect(imageRectangle, Panel3.DisplayRectangle)
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Panel3.Width, Panel3.Height, picUser.Image.PixelFormat)
        Panel3.DrawToBitmap(bmp, safeCropRectangle)
        bmp.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

What can I do to remove the scroll bars? I already used the panel.VerticalScroll.Visible = false before the lines of code but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `DrawToBitmap` to save modified image inside PictureBox.
Follow the below procedure.

1. Create a new bitmap with the same size and Pixel Format as the picturebox.
2. Call the `DrawToBitmap` function of the picturebox.

For more details, examine the following example program. Using `DrawToBitmap`, you can set the `PictureBox.SizeMode` property to whatever you want and save the modified image to a file.

***PS***: This example code is for giving the idea of how you can save the image of `PictureBox` in any `SizeMode`, not for providing a solution to the question with/without its complete details.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace PictureboxZoomSave
    Public Class MainForm
        Inherits Form

        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
        End Sub

        Private openFileDialog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
        Private saveFileDialog As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
        Private image As Image

        Private Sub OpenImageButton_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg; *.png"

            If openFileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                If image IsNot Nothing Then image.Dispose()
                image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog.FileName)
                pictureBox1.Image = image
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub SaveImageButton_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg; *.png"

            If saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim bitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, image.PixelFormat)
                pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height))
                bitmap.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName)
            End If
        End Sub

        <STAThread>
        Private Shared Sub Main()
            Application.EnableVisualStyles()
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
            Application.Run(New MainForm())
        End Sub

        Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer = Nothing

        Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
            If disposing AndAlso (components IsNot Nothing) Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If

            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Sub

        Private Sub InitializeComponent()
            Me.pictureBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
            Me.OpenImageButton = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
            Me.SaveImageButton = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
            (CType((Me.pictureBox1), System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)).BeginInit()
            Me.SuspendLayout()
            Me.pictureBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
            Me.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1"
            Me.pictureBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 191)
            Me.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0
            Me.pictureBox1.TabStop = False
            Me.OpenImageButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(229, 12)
            Me.OpenImageButton.Name = "button1"
            Me.OpenImageButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
            Me.OpenImageButton.TabIndex = 1
            Me.OpenImageButton.Text = "Open"
            Me.OpenImageButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
            AddHandler Me.OpenImageButton.Click, New System.EventHandler(AddressOf Me.OpenImageButton_click)
            Me.SaveImageButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(229, 42)
            Me.SaveImageButton.Name = "button2"
            Me.SaveImageButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
            Me.SaveImageButton.TabIndex = 2
            Me.SaveImageButton.Text = "Save"
            Me.SaveImageButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
            AddHandler Me.SaveImageButton.Click, New System.EventHandler(AddressOf Me.SaveImageButton_click)
            Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F)
            Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
            Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.SaveImageButton)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.OpenImageButton)
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.pictureBox1)
            Me.Name = "PictureBoxZoomSave"
            Me.Text = "PictureBoxZoomSave"
            (CType((Me.pictureBox1), System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)).EndInit()
            Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        End Sub

        Private pictureBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
        Private OpenImageButton As System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Private SaveImageButton As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Going to test this and update you later.

Comment: According to the required output screenshot,  the size of the output bitmap is the client size of the container, the `Panel`, not the size of the scaled `pbox`. Consequently, draw the `Panel` to the bitmap. `pnl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pnl.ClientRectangle)`.

Comment: Hi jtxjopt and dr.null,

Comment: Hi @jtxjopt,

First off, I just want to thank you two for answering my question. I have successfully saved an image by doing what you guys suggested. I searched online and tweaked your codes a bit and it works. I saved the zoomed image in relation to the location and size of the panel within the zoomed image. 

HOWEVER, the output image has also drawn the horizontal and vertical scrollbars of the panel. My question now is how to remove the scrollbars to the output?

Comment: @dr.null thanks for the reply. Could you help me on my followup question? I edited my original post, kindly see if you have an insight on the matter. Thanks.

Comment: @HumbleJ. If you dont want the scrollbars in the saved image, use the `DrawToBitmap` function of the PictureBox instead of `Panel` as in my answer.

Comment: @jtxkopt Yeah I figured that out. But how do I get the location of the rectangle on the picturebox that is the same as the one showing on my panel?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to crop the displayed region of a zoomed in image. If so, you can achieve that through many ways and techniques, `DrawToBitmap` is the easiest approach. Please note:

- Using the `PictureBox` draw method and size doesn't output the required result because it's size changes when you apply the zoom/scale factor. In other words, the result is either a smaller or bigger image of the original one according to the zoom factor.
- The output image size is the `Panel` client size (WYSIWYG).

Hence, you just need to do:

```vb
Dim imgRect = pnl.ClientRectangle
Dim bmp = New Bitmap(imgRect.Width, imgRect.Height, pbox.Image.PixelFormat)
pnl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, imgRect)
'Save it...
```

where *pbox* is the `PictureBox` and *pnl* is it's parent `Panel`.

[image: SO73442247]

That's it all if that is what you are after.

Comment: Oh my god. I'm blaming VS2019 on this one (or maybe I'm the one at fault here) because whenever I try to type ClientRectangle method for the panel, it doesn't show anything with that method name. So I used DisplayRectangle instead, which I found out with your code, is not the same. OMG. 

Thank you very much, I think this one is solved already. Thank you very much kind sir for your help. Sorry for asking too many questions, I am just a newbie using vb.net. God bless you.

Comment: @HumbleJ. No problem. You're welcome. To see the advanced members like the `ClientRectangle` property in the `IntelliSense`, go to `Tools` - `Options` - `Text Editor` - `Basic` and untick the `Hide advanced members` option. Good luck.